# what happens when you input things like 12ab to scanf("%d",&argu)?

Tags: c, scanf

I came across this problem when I want to check what I input is number. The `scanf` function will return 1 if I successfully input a number. So here is what I wrote:

```
int argu;
while(scanf("%d",&argu)!=1){
    printf("Please input a number!\n");
}
```

But when I input things like `abcd` to it, the loop would go forever and not stop for prompt.

I looked it up online and found that it had something to do with the cache and I need to clean it up so `scanf` can get new data. So I tried `fflush` but it didn't work.

Then I saw this:

```
int argu,j;
while(scanf("%d",&argu)!=1){
    printf("Please input a number!\n");
    while((j=getchar())!='\n' && j != '\n');
}
```

Then when I input things like 'abcd' it worked well and it prompted for my input. But when I input things like '12ab', it wouldn't work again.

So is there a way I can check the input for `scanf("%d", &argu)` is actually a number and prompt for another input if it isn't?

**EDIT**:

I saw the answers and solved my problem by using `while(*eptr != '\n')`.

Notice that the `fgets` function actually reads '\n' into the array and `gets` doesn't. So be careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to read a full line, using `fgets()`, and then inspecting it, rather than trying to parse "on the fly" from the input stream.

It's easier to ignore non-valid input, that way.

Use `fgets()` and then just `strtol()` to convert to a number, it will make it easy to see if there is trailing data after the number.

For instance:

```
char line[128];

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL)
{
   char *eptr = NULL;
   long v = strtol(line, &eptr, 10);
   if(eptr == NULL || !isspace(*eptr))
   {
     printf("Invalid input: %s", line);
     continue;
   }
   /* Put desired processing code here. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know strtol. Learned a lot!

Comment: sorry, can you explain `if(eptr == NULL || !isspace(*eptr))`? when using the code you give,inputs like '12 34' are accepted but they shouldn't be. when I input '1234'what the eptr would point to and how about '12ab' and '12 34'?

Comment: Please review [Correct usage of `strtol()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176123/correct-usage-of-strtol).  The `&eptr` argument is not set to NULL by `strtol()` on failure to convert; it is set to `line` (its first argument).

Answer (score 2):

> But when I input things like abcd to it, the loop would go forever and not stop for prompt.

That's because if `scanf` encounters a character that does not match the conversion specifier, it leaves it in the input stream.  Basically, what's happening is that `scanf` reads the character `a` from the input stream, determines that it's not a valid match for the `%d` conversion specifier, and then pushes it back onto the input stream.  The next time through the loop it does the same thing.  And again.  And again.  And again.

`fflush` is not a good solution, because it isn't defined to work on input streams.

For the input `"12ab"`, `scanf` will read and convert `"12"`, leaving `"ab"` in the input stream.

The best solution is to read all your input as text, then convert to numeric types using `strtol` (for integral values) and `strtod` (for real values).  For example:

```
char input[SIZE]; // assume SIZE is big enough for whatever input we get
int value;

if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) != NULL)
{
  char *chk;
  int tmp = (int) strtol(input, &chk, 10);
  if (isspace(*chk) || *chk == 0)
    value = tmp;
  else
    printf("%s is not a valid integer string\n", input);
}
```

`chk` points to the first character in the input stream that isn't a decimal digit.  If this character is not whitespace or the 0 terminator, then the input string wasn't a valid integer.  This will detect and reject inputs like `"12ab"` as well as `"abcd"`.

`scanf` is a good solution if you know your input is always going to be properly formed and well-behaved.  If there's a chance that your input *isn't* well-behaved, use `fgets` and convert as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to get input as a string and check for non-numeric characters in it. If input is valid convert string to int by `sscanf(str,"%d",&i);` or else diplay error.

Comment: The easiest way to check for non-numeric characters is to call `sscanf()` and see whether it succeeds.  You have to decide whether trailing non-numeric characters matter.  If so, you probably use `if (sscanf, str, "%d %n", &i, &posn) != 1 || str[posn] != '\0') { …report trouble… }`.  That allows and ignores trailing white space after the number; if even that is unacceptable, you remove the blank in the format and probably test for `'\n'` instead of `'\0'` — unless you removed the newline already (in which case the test remains for `'\0'`).

Answer (score 0):

Just call `scanf("%*[^\n]\n")` inside the loop, and it will discard the "cache".

Comment: That's because the behavior for `fflush` isn't defined for input streams. See the [C language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), section 7.19.5.2, paragraph 2.

Comment: You are both right. Hope the edit, though, is now correct (based on the standard).

Comment: The trailing newline in the proposed format string is a UX disaster if the input comes from a human.  You have to type something other than white space (newlines are white space) to get the `scanf()` call shown to work, which requires the user to know what they'll need to type next before this input finishes.

Answer (score -1):

Call `scanf("%*[^\n]\n")` inside the loop. This should be enough to discard anything associated with the cache.

Comment: The trailing newline in the proposed format string is a UX disaster if the input comes from a human.  You have to type something other than white space (newlines are white space) to get the `scanf()` call shown to work, which requires the user to know what they'll need to type next before this input finishes.