# What exactly happens when I input a string "abcd" to scanf("%d", &var)?

Tags: c, gcc, scanf

Inputting a string to

```
scanf("%d",&var) returns 0.
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139092/what-happens-when-you-input-things-like-12ab-to-scanfd-argu), but the explanation of what happens internally is not provided. What is provided is a way to handle the situation.

How exactly does GCC handle strings passed to scanf("%d",&var) and why is the return value 0 in this case?

Comment: That's actually your standard C library, not Gcc, what's doing something here (ignoring built-in functions). And Gcc never sees the string passed in at runtime.

Comment: And I don't fully understand your question (or at least not, what isn't answered in the linked question). Is it, how a byte can be read from a stream and then pushed back in case it is an invalid byte? And for implementation details: Take a look at e.g. the `glibc` source code.

Comment: > _"Is it, how a byte can be read from a stream and then pushed back in case it is an invalid byte?"_

That is exactly what I want to understand.

Comment: [Here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfscanf.c) is the aforementioned source code, they use the built-in function `_IO_sputbackc` defined in [genops.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/genops.c). You may also want to take a look at the standard C functions `ungetc` and `fseek`. An answer to your question will depend on the platform in use, but at least you have a few points where to start now…

Answer (score 3):

Upon successful completion, `scanf` shall return the number of successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be zero in the event of an early matching failure.

On seeing `%d` in format string, `scanf` expects an `int` type data. When you enter string in place of `int`, `scanf` starts reading input and when sees character, stop reading and returns `0` .

Answer (score 3):

On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. So, if you don't type a number, the number of items read will be 0.

Refer to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ for more info